# IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect fails with D3DERR_INVALIDCALL

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I'm trying to blit data from Offscreen Plain Surface to Render Target surface with [IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d9helper/nf-d3d9helper-idirect3ddevice9-stretchrect), however it returns D3DERR_INVALIDCALL.

According to documentation this function should work for offscreen to render target operation, so not sure why it might fail.

BTW if I create the offscreen surface with `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` flag - then `StretchRect` works, however I need it to be in system memory, so I use `D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM` flag and that makes `StretchRect` to fail.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found out that `IDirect3DDevice9::UpdateSurface` works for this purpose, it doesn't support scaling though. However one can use it to copy the data to a intermediate `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` surface, and then use `IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect` to blit intermediate to final Render Target surface.